# Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit and 32 bit on two drives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I recently acquired a 64 bit machine which works well (AMD 64 3800+). I had an old Dell P4 machine which I had configured to dual-boot 11.10 32-bit and Win XP SP3.

I wish to install the disk from my old machine into the 64 bit machine and keep everything as is on it to run along with the 64 bit 11.10 installation.

Can I use the install disk to set up grub to multi-boot the other disk (e.g. Win XP and 11.10 32 bit in addition to 11.10 64 bit)?
Or, will I have to manually set this configuration up with the 64 bit loader?

Comment: 16.. bit? where it says 16 bit Ubntu 11.10? or why you say it's 16 bit?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `update-grub` right from your current install should do all this for you.

`/etc/grub/30_os-prober` seems to be what handles all the nitty gritty details, but you don't really have to care about that.

My suggestion? Plug in the other HD, try `update-grub` and see what happens. It *ought* to all just work, but if not, come back and edit the question :)